# FitVids and Grid-A-Licious jQuery Plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi — I'm having a few issues getting http://fitvidsjs.com to play nicely with http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/ within a tumblr theme. I guess it's a clash somewhere. I'm a bit of a novice with the jQuery and wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction. Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

I think both of the plugins are doing their jobs correctly, there are only some height issues with the videos. FitVids.JS is creating a padding above the video container and also the video doesn't have a height.

Try adding this to your CSS:-

```
.fluid-width-video-wrapper { padding-top:0 !important; }
.fluid-width-video-wrapper, .fluid-width-video-wrapper iframe { height:300px; }
```

I have just entered a custom value for height. You should customize it according to your preference.

Comment: Cheers, but I think it has more to do with the video not scaling up to fill the space created by the fitvids plugin, i.e. the extra padding.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by executing...

```
$('iframe').css('height', '100%');
```